# run a jquery function after each loop completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where i am running a jquery function and in that function i have an each loop. The each loop takes some time for processing and that is why the next statement executes before each completes. This creates a problem for me. I want a function to execute when each completes. My function is as follows:-

```
function myFunc() {
// Do something

$.each(mylist, function (i, val) {
    // do something
    filepicker.store(myList, function (stored_fpfile) {
                    console.log("Store successful:", JSON.stringify(stored_fpfile));
                }, function (FPError) {
                   // Error
                }, function (progress) {
                    console.log("Loading: " + progress + "%");
                }
                );
});

CallMyFunction();
}
```

Call my function executes before each loop finishes.

I dont want to use count of the list to detect and run my procedure. I want a reliable solution.

I am using the InkFilePicker API to store files to Amazon

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $.each is synchronous your function will be called only after each is finished unless you have some asynchronous processing inside each that will continue after each is finished.

Comment: `Call my function executes before each loop finishes.` that isn't possible, $.each is synchronous. If you mean wait until all the asynchronous stuff inside of the each completes, we'll need to know what those asynchronous things are.

Comment: @KevinB Edit made to question to show what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating deferred objects for each iteration that are then stored in an array. Then, after the each, you can wait until all those deferred objects are complete to run your other function.

```
function myFunc() {
    // Do something
    var promiseArray = $.map(mylist, function (i, val) {
        return $.Deferred(function(def){
            // do something
            filepicker.store(val, function (stored_fpfile) {
                def.resolve(stored_fpfile);
            }, function (FPError) {
                def.reject(FPError);
            }, function (progress) {
                def.notify(progress); // won't actually be accurate
            });        
        }).promise();
    });
    $.when.apply($,promiseArray).done(function(){
        console.log(arguments); // array of results from onSuccess callbacks
        CallMyFunction();
    })

}
```

Comment: I changed one part, i changed `filepicker.store(mylist` to `filepicker.store(val` because it doesn't make sense for it to be `mylist`. In what way did this not work? why didn't it work? i can create a demo of this code with another method similar to the filepicker that does work.

Comment: If any one of the calls to filepicker.store results in error, the callmyfunction will not happen.

Comment: I have demo this function in front of me and it is not working. I can give you team viewer f you want.

Comment: That isn't enough information for me to help you make it work.

Comment: What about a team viewer or gotomeeting session?

Comment: I can't. Here's a fiddle showing the code working, assuming that all calls to .store result in success. http://jsfiddle.net/g7m7H/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the store is a wrapper around an AJAX object. You should test the progress and when it is completed call CallMyFunction, like so before the call to each:

```
items = myList.length;
```

And inside each:

```
...
function (progress) {
    console.log("Loading: " + progress + "%");
    if (--items === 0)
    {
        CallMyFunction();
    }
}
...
```

There aren't any counter arguments, performance is not impacted by this, you're sending data over the Internet which is the real bottleneck.

This is also reliable. In case of error you should decrement with --items too.